# How to include js on category pages Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category-products, page

Hello i am using magento 1

i am not sure how can i include the below js in magento category pages frontend.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

https://swiperjs.com/get-started/

How to ideally include the above js on category pages ?

Answer (score 1):

Please add code in `catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <head>  
        <script src="js/custom.js"/>
    </head>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thanks and Happy Coding.

Comment: Hello, where to put this file in directory ?

Comment: [root]/app/design/frontend/[theme]/[package]/layout/ and put in it.

Comment: For Magento 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but here it is.

I think the ideal answer would be to download those files into your filesystem and then use the `head` blocks "addItem" method to include them using your local.xml file under the `<catalog_category_view>` handle.

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name><your_js_file_here></name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name><your_css_file_here></name></action>
    </reference>
</catelog_category_view>
```

This has the benefit of making them internal files to be included rather than external.

On the other hand you may not want those files on your server in which case you need to link to external resources.

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script src="<js_URL_here>"></script></action>
        <action method="addLinkRel">
            <rel>stylesheet</rel>
            <href><stylesheet_URL_here></href>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catelog_category_view>
```

Note: Both of these changes can go in `app/design/frontend/default/<your_theme>/layout/local.xml`